# Can anyone help me with a MYSQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I've created this Maria MYSQL db for a mock animal sanctuary.

I have an issue with a stored procedure I've coded to add animals of one of the existing species I've included in the specie table.

I've had no success adding new animals with my logic so far. Can anyone help me out?

Here's my procedure code, animal and specie tables details:

**Animal**

```
{

id  name    dob      specie_id  weight size  active diet_type_id
1   Poof  2021-12-13    3       5.0    2.0     0          3
2   Piff  2021-12-13    2       3.0    6.0     1          1
3   Paff  2021-12-13    1       5.0    2.0     1          2
4   Tuff  2021-12-13    3       5.0    2.0     1          3

}
```

**Specie**

```
{ id  name
  1   Amur Leopard
  2   African Forest Elephant
  3   Asian Black Bear
}
```

My procedure:

```
{CREATE PROCEDURE `sanctuary`.`addAnimal`(
    name VARCHAR(100),
    dob DATE,
    specieName VARCHAR(100),
    weight DOUBLE,
    sizeValue DOUBLE,
    dietTypeName VARCHAR(100)
)
proc_Exit:begin
    declare specieIdDB INT;
    declare dietIdDB INT;
    SELECT id into specieIdDB FROM specie WHERE name = specieName;
    IF ISNULL(specieIdDB)
    then
        select "Specie not found";
        LEAVE proc_Exit;
    end if;
    SELECT id INTO dietIdDB FROM diet_type WHERE name = dietTypeName;
    IF ISNULL(dietIdDB)
    then
        select "diet type not found";
        LEAVE proc_Exit;
    end if;
    INSERT INTO `animal` (`name`, `dob`, `specie_id`, `weight`, `size`, `active`, `diet_type_id`) 
    VALUES (name, dob, specieIdDB, weight, sizeValue, b'1', dietIdDB);
END

}
```

Comment: You don't put `{}` around MySQL procedures.

Comment: You don't need `proc_Exit`. You can just use `RETURN` to exit the function.

Comment: Cool I'll try that. 
My bad, I thought I had to use "{ }" just to post my code on stackoverflow

Comment: No. You make code blocks either by indenting it 4 spaces or putting triple-backticks on the lines before and after.

Comment: `{}` is the toolbar button you can press to format code. You don't have to _type_ brackets.